# Unable to find Arc/Curve tool in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, digitizing, true-curves

I am trying to digitize curved roads in QGIS but cannot find the right tool.

I want somthing like end point arc segment in arcmap as shown in figure below.

[image: arcmaps editor end point arc segment]

Comment: Would this help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215484/making-lines-curvy-using-qgis