# QGIS specified make_line curved between points

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator, curved, qgis-expression, st-makeline

[This question is a continuation of this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/309801/175499)

I want to draw curved lines between specific points that are related to each other.

On my points layer each point has:
unique FID and relation field to another point in the same layer "Precondition"

```
make_line(
    start_point($geometry),
    translate(
        centroid($geometry),
        $length/10,
        $length/10
    ),
    end_point($geometry), 
    geometry(
        get_feature(
            'point_layer',
            'fid',
            Precondition
        )
    )
)
```

There's something wrong with the code and it's not displaying the lines... what's wrong?

Comment: Is your FID field capitalised like so? If it is, you will need to capitalise it the same in your expression. With that aside, your expression works for me.