How to create a curved LineString in QGIS from a CSV file with latitude and longitude points, specifying a curving angle?
I have a CSV file with the following columns:
DepartLon: Longitude of the departure point
DepartLat: Latitude of the departure point
DestLon: Longitude of the destination point
DestLat: Latitude of the destination point
I've already created a straight LineString between these points in QGIS. However, I need to create a curved LineString instead, with a specific curving angle.
I've explored the following approaches without success:

Geometry Algorithms: I've looked into QGIS's built-in geometry algorithms but haven't found a suitable one for creating curved lines based on coordinates and an angle.
Custom Plugins: I've searched for plugins that might offer this functionality, but I haven't found any that directly address my specific requirement.

I'm aiming to create a flowpath that's not simply a straight line but rather has a curved shape, with the curvature determined by a specified angle. The resulting LineString should be based on the given longitude and latitude coordinates.

Maybe this can give iyou some ideas.: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215484/making-lines-curvy-in-qgis. Besides this, you might want to be more specific: how far apart are your points, in which projection do you want the line to be curved?
